# How to set a default value to server generated time?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is is possible to have a datetime field which has as a default server generated time during save?

```
class ADoc(Document):
    ...
    created_at = me.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

This model has two issues:

1. `created_at` will get a value during model instance creation, not the time when the document is saved into the database.
2. Client time is used, which might differ from the server time -- I'd like to always use server time as the time source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the operator [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) ?

**UPD**:
I like pymongo, but I think that can be for MongoEngine, you can try:

```
collection = Animal._get_collection()
collection.update({}, {"$currentDate": {"date": 1}}, upsert=true)
```

[example here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#inheritance)

Comment: Yes, and the question is how to use this operator in a MongoEngine model

Comment: note that "$currentDate" is going to assign the mongo db engine current time, not the flask app current server time. If the flask-pymongo app is on a different server in different time zone than the mongo db engine then the time may differ.

Comment: @VelinGeorgiev I think timezone is not important here, because `$currentDate` assigns time in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `_id` field contains the timestamp on creation.
You can access it like this [`ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/).

There's also [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) and [`new Date`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Date/).

Comment: Yes, I could use `ObjectId`, but: 1) It doesn't have microseconds; 2) I don't know how to [make it server side generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473295/server-side-generated-id); 3) It's kind of changes the meaning of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I would use defined by me insert method in my ADoc class:

```
from datetime import datetime

class ADoc:
    def __init__(self, db, config):
        self.docs= db['docs']
        self.config = config

    def insert(self, document):
        item = {
           'name': document['name'],
           'created': datetime.utcnow()
        }
        self.docs.insert_one(item)
```

then simply execute the method when needed

```
client = MongoClient(DB_URL)
db = client['yourDb']

doc = "your new doc"
adoc = ADoc(db, app.config)

adoc.insert(doc)
```

Comment: This uses time generated on the client. I need the time to be generated on the MongoDB server using something like [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)

Comment: Then as alex10 said you should go with something like on this example: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/update/#update-top-level-fields