# Server side generated id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

The [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#document-ids) say:

> Usually, the id will be generated automatically by the database server
>   when the object is save, meaning that you may only access the id field
>   once a document has been saved:
>
> ```
> >>> page = Page(title="Test Page")
> >>> page.id
> >>> page.save()
> >>> page.id
> ObjectId('123456789abcdef000000000')
> ```

But I have found that it's not true:

```
ipdb> 
> .../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py(386)gen()
    385                     if '_id' not in doc:
--> 386                         doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
    387
```

So `pymongo` generates `id` on the client side.

How to make MongoEngine to generate the ids on server side?

Comment: I how found this: [http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#writes-and-ids](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#writes-and-ids)

Comment: @Valijon please read the question carefully.

Comment: I see. Seems to be a bug for python driver. No solution

Comment: @Valijon I think it's expected behavior in PyMongo, but I wonder how to work around this in MongoEngine.

Comment: Why don't you generate `_id` by yourself? UUID is more usefull than ObjectId

Comment: @Valijon how is it more useful?

Comment: Well, any primitive id is more practical than object. You don't need to worry serialize/deserialize. Such documents can be exported as standard JSON. Sharding with ObjectId `_id` is less efficent. In particular, UUID string can be generated by different strategy [https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).